# Getting NullPointerException with Object Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program to mimic the "Deal or No Deal" game.

Background on Deal or No Deal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deal_or_No_Deal

In working up to the final product, I have written various classes.  However, I am trying to test one of my classes, and continue to get the `NullPointerException.`

I wrote a class called Box, that creates "box" objects.  The box object is the actual box that a player picks.  It consists of a true/false value and a double boxValue.  The `boolean variable` denotes whether it's open/closed (true for open, false for closed).  The double boxValue is the actual value assigned to the box.

```
public class Box {

//instance fields
private double boxValue; // the amount of $ in each box
private boolean openClose; // whether or not the box is closed


//Constructor
public Box(double boxValue) {
    this.openClose = false;      
    this.boxValue = boxValue;

    if (boxValue < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Box value must be greater than 0");
    }
}
}
```

I have written another class called BoxList as well.  This creates a Box object array that will serve as the playing board, when combined with further classes that I am planning to write.  The main idea is that the constructor in BoxList creates the array by using a passed in `double array` as a paramater, and then creates a Box Object array of the same length of the passed in double array, and assigns the double value of each element of the `parameter array`, to the value of the Box object `array` as the corresponding element.

I wrote a sample main method to test, but when I try to get the value of a particular `element` of a Box in the BoxList array, I get the NullPointerException.  Can anyone offer advice to help trouble shoot this.

(These are snips of a larger program...I already wrote so much that I didn't want to clog further)

```
public class BoxList {

private Box[] boxArray;

public BoxList(double[] monetaryAmounts) {
    Box[] boxArray = new Box[monetaryAmounts.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
        boxArray[i] = new Box(monetaryAmounts[i]);
    }

}

public double getValue(int index) {
    return boxArray[index].getValue();
}


// A sample main method to test out various object methods
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] monetaryAmounts = {.5, 1, 3, 7.5, 8, 10}; // test array

    BoxList test = new BoxList(monetaryAmounts); 

    System.out.println(test.getValue(0));

}
```

Comment: What line do you get the Null Pointer Exception on?  Point that out to us with a comment.

Comment: Getting it when I excecute the println statement at the end of BoxList (for the getValue method).  Exception thrown at `return boxArray[index].getValue();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You initialized your `boxArray` properly, but you initialized a local variable `boxArray`, and your instance variable `boxArray` was unreferenced, so Java initialized it to `null`, causing the exception.  Change

```
Box[] boxArray = new Box[monetaryAmounts.length];
```

to

```
boxArray = new Box[monetaryAmounts.length];
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll mark as answered in the correct time span.